# Using Swift class in Objective c. Undeclared identifier error ocurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'd created a test project to try Swift. But I've stuck on importing Swift class into Objective-C class. Project name is "TestSwift1". And I have set Defines Module in Packaging to YES. XCode-Beta3

I have next code:

```
//swift SwtClass.swift  
import Foundation

class SwtClass
{
     var title = ""
}
//Objective-C ObjClass.h

@interface ObjClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;

@end

//Objective-c ObjClass.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ObjClass.h"
#import <testSwift1-Swift.h>

@implementation ObjClass

- (void)doSomething
{
      SwtClass* b; // Error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'SwtClass'"
                   // Error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'b'"

      NSLog(@"something is done");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While writing this question I've found solution. And as always it was very simple but took a while maybe this will save somebody a couple of minutes.

To use Swift class(that **is not a subclass** of NSObject) in Objective-C don't forget to mark it with **@objc** as it said here ["Using Swift from Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). My Swift class had to look like this:

```
//swift SwtClass.swift  
import Foundation

@objc class SwtClass
{
     var title = ""
}
```

Comment: If you make `SwtClass` a subclass of `NSObject` then `@objc` is implied. Its a rare case that you have a class that doesn't inherit from an ObjC class (at least currently)

Comment: @Vitaliy1 You should have not deleted the question on casting to NSManagedObjectId, it could be helpful for others. You can recover it.

Comment: For some reason `@objc` didn't work for me, but subclassing `NSObject` did. With `@objc class SomeClass` I get the error (pointing to that class declaration) "Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc". I just need to subclass `NSObject`, no need of `@objc`.

Comment: My issue ended up being it was shared across modules so it needed to be public to be accessible.